# Trigger a job after the success of previous job

Tags: github-actions

I'm looking for guidance on modifying my GitHub Actions workflow to trigger a job build automatically after the successful completion of a "validate" job. Currently, the workflow looks like the following:

validate.yml

```
name: Validate

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "DEVELOP" ]
    tags:
      - v**
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "DEVELOP" ]
    tags:
      - v**

jobs:
  validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ....
```

build.yml

```
name: Build

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - Validate
    types:
      - completed
  workflow_dispatch:



jobs:
  build:
    name: Push to Docker image to GitHub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    .....
```

Comment: Could you please share more details in your questions? What did you modify? What do you expect to happen, or what is not working as expecting? Which documentation are you following? What configurations did you try (or is this the only one)?

Comment: In this scenario, the objective is to ensure that the Build job commences only after the successful completion of the Validate job. The provided sample code above requires modification to meet this requirement for the sequence: Job [Validate] → Job[Build].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the Git documents from [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-based-on-the-conclusion-of-another-workflow). I want the 'build' job to run after the 'validate' job successfully completes. Therefore, in the 'build' job, I need to check if the 'preview' job was successful before starting.

Answer:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - Validate
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  build:
    name: Push to Docker image to GitHub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
....
```